# "歩くための靴" VS "履くための靴 "

Tags: meaning, kanji

I was doing some JLPT listening exercises on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/-SbVXO2ogjs?t=440) and found these two expressions which I couldn't find any references on online dictionaries.

I am looking for clarifications on the matter.

1)履くための靴

2)歩くための靴

履くための靴 is the one on the video. It was translated as "Inside Shoes". Because I couldn't find anything on Jisho.org, I searched for the expression on google images. And then I found the second expression (歩くための靴), which I believe, by the kanji, could mean "Outside Shoes"/"Shoes for walking" as contrasting to the first option.

Comment: In that video, 中ではくための靴 = "shoes to be worn inside" = "inside shoes". We usually simply say 中ぐつ or うわばき, but seems expressed circumlocutory to reduce the vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

履くための靴 means "shoes for wearing", but this makes little sense in isolation. Here the video says 中で履くための靴, where this 中で means "indoors". 中で履くための靴 literally means "shoes for wearing indoors". This type of shoes are usually simply called [上履き](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uwabaki) in Japanese, but slippers would do if you don't own ones.

There is a word 外履き (*sotobaki*, "outside shoes"), but this is used only when the contrast with 上履き is important. If we simply say 靴 without context, it refers to 外履き.

歩くための靴 is not a fixed phrase. Maybe it refers to something like sneakers or light trekking shoes, but its meaning should depend on the context.